# Iterate and input data into a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, iteration

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that is a small selection of strings. Let's call the column 'A' and all of the values in it are `string_1`, `string_2`, `string_3`.

Now, I want to add another column and fill it with numeric values that correspond to the strings.

I created a dictionary

```
d = { 'string_1' : 1, 'string_2' : 2, 'string_3': 3}
```

I then initialized the new column:

```
df['B'] = pd.Series(index=df.index)
```

Now, I want to fill it with the integer values.  I can call the values associated with the strings in the dictionary by:

```
for s in df['A']:
   n = d[s]
```

That works fine, but I've tried using just plain `df['B'] = n` to fill the new column in the for-loop, but that doesn't work, and I've tried to figure out indexing with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can just call `map`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(d)
```

This will perform the lookup and fill the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fill as an empty column, you can simply populate this with an apply:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(d.get)
```